# How can I execute a command from the text editor?

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4 and Steam need a workaround:

```
    LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam
```

It gets annoying to put it in the terminal every time I play. Is there a way to put the command in a text document, and make that document execute the command when I click on the file? Thanks.

Comment: what editor are you using?

Answer (score 5):

```
gedit script.sh
```

type your command in the file

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

or you can use an alias if you usually open steam by command line

open .bashrc with your text editor

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

add this line in the end

```
alias steam='"LD_PRELOAD=/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6" steam'
```

---

The above idea to make an `alias` is a very good one, and can be built into your desktop launcher by editing the `~/.profile` file, which is functionally similar to `~/.bashrc`. Open `~/.profile` in `gedit` and add the same `alias steam='"LD_PRELOAD=/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6" steam'` to it, and it will automatically execute that way when you launch Steam from a desktop icon, or your dock/launcher/whatever.

Comment: i really like the idea of an alias. I think, though, that the command should be `alias steam='LD_PRELOAD="/usr/\$LIB/libstdc++.so.6" steam'`

Answer (score 1):

To add a different point of view to the previous answer, you can always use the reverse-i-search in the terminal, which search through all the commands you have executed.

To use it, press `CTRL+R` and try to type same characters to identify your previous command. For example, `CTRL+R` and then writing `steam` should give you the command you want. Then, just press Enter to execute it.

You can also add a tag to the command to identify it. For example, you can run the program using

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam #mytag
```

and then `CTRL+R`, then `#mytag` should give you this exact command.

---

If you still want to use a script, maybe the most immediate way is to execute

```
echo "LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam" > steam_script.sh
chmod u+x steam_script.sh
```

and then launch the file using `./steam_script.sh` from the directory in which you have created the file.